# ASP.NET Core 2.2 -> 3.0 upgrade. env.IsDevelopment() not found

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I upgraded an existing 2.2 project to 3.0. I copied the new code for Program/Startup from a new 3.0 project to my existing 2.2 project. It worked, but the `IsDevelopment()` below:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }
}
```

Results in this error:

> 'IWebHostEnvironment' does not contain a definition for 'IsDevelopment' and the best extension method overload 'HostingEnvironmentExtensions.IsDevelopment(IHostingEnvironment)' requires a receiver of type 'IHostingEnvironment'

The same line did not caused a newly created 3.0 project. What do I need to modify/add to the project upgraded from 2.2?

Comment: What about blessed vegetables?

Answer (score 258, accepted):

The new `IHostEnvironment`, `IsDevelopment`, `IsProduction` etc. extension methods are in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` namespace which may need to be added to your app.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7749

Comment: No need to install the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting package, just add the using statement as mentioned in @Greg's post.

Comment: so then we need both Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting and using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
at the same time... Wonder how that works? Class name from one package but its method from another?

Comment: Actually,the asp.net core 3.0 do not have such issue now.It has been fixed.

Answer (score 147):

As Rena says `IsDevelopment` has been moved to `IHostEnvironment` Interface in the 
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting Namespace

I just had to add the

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
```

and then I could use `IsDevelopment()` as before.

Comment: Thanks a million, this answer helped me to solve the exception. Was migrating asp.net core 23.0 to core 3.1.  just add this library and all worked like sharp. Billiant!

Answer (score 2):

int the extension:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

public static class HostingEnvironmentExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot GetAppConfiguration(this IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        return AppConfigurations.Get(env.ContentRootPath, env.EnvironmentName, env.IsDevelopment());
    }
}
```