# .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation() results in The type or namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-core

In a .NET 6 / ASP.NET Core app after adding the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` Nuget package and adding

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

I get this error, when opening a view:

```bash
The type or namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

                Write(__tagHelperExecutionContext.Output);
                __tagHelperExecutionContext = __tagHelperScopeManager.End();
                WriteLiteral("\n\n</html>\n");
            }
            #pragma warning restore 1998
            [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]

            public IWebHostEnvironment HostingEnv { get; private set; }

            [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
            public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.IModelExpressionProvider ModelExpressionProvider { get; private set; }
            [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
            public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IUrlHelper Url { get; private set; }
            [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
            public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IViewComponentHelper Component { get; private set; }
```

`IWebHostEnvironment` is referenced in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@inject IWebHostEnvironment HostingEnv
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
...
</html>
```

**Note**:

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73087276/90800) works, however, Rider (and maybe ReSharper) might mark `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.` in the `@inject` statement as redundant.

I don't know why this happens, but I added this above the `@inject` statement line:

```
@* ReSharper disable once RedundantNameQualifier *@
```

Also, read [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73085015/addrazorruntimecompilation-results-in-the-type-or-namespace-name-iwebhostenv/73087276#comment129085230_73087276) regarding the `IsDevelopment()` error I got after using the full qualified reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried fully qualifying the namespace and making it

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment HostingEnv
```

If that works then I recall there being a difference in how _ViewImports files are processed during runtime compilation versus standard, it doesn’t cascade the same way. You may therefore find that your existing _ViewImports files aren’t all being read.

Comment: Now I get `'IWebHostEnvironment' does not contain a definition for 'IsDevelopment' ` in this line  `@if (HostingEnv.IsDevelopment())`.

Comment: Adding the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` package and putting `using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;` on top of my `_Layout.cshtml` fixed the `IsDevelopment` issue. (via https://stackoverflow.com/a/58072137/90800)

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of implicit usings in C# 10, this may happen because of implicit usings in your .csproj:

```
<Using Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" />
```

Your razor files can be compiled well in the compile time, but failing during the runtime compilation because of missing namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`. Solution is to add the `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`  in your `_ViewImports.cshtml`.

Comment: I can't believe it took so long to find this answer. You saved me so much time, thank you. I wonder if this has been reported somewhere as a known bug. The runtime compilation should take into account GlobalUsings.cs. It doesn't warn you that these will be ignored and must be added to that _ViewImports file. Not a dev-friendly experience!

Comment: Might be related to this: https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/7539